# forEach on an Array

Tags: node.js, foreach

I'm a little baffled. For some reason this won't work:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(function(num) {
  console.log(num)
})
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined
```

However, this will:

```
var nums = [1, 2, 3]

nums.forEach(function(num) {
  console.log(num)
})
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: What version of Node are you running? It works for me.

Comment: The latest: v0.10.31

Comment: What's the output of `Array.prototype.forEach` right before the first statement? Does it output a function?

Comment: It seems to be because [I'm not using semicolons](http://jsfiddle.net/fcn4wa7k).

Comment: Oh, YEAH! It seems (at least in your fiddle) to be interpreting that you are setting your foo variable to [1,2,3]. `var foo = 'bar' [1, 2, 3].forEach(function(num) {
  console.log(num)
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out it was because [I'm not using semicolons](http://jsfiddle.net/fcn4wa7k), and the preceding code conflicted.

```
var foo = 'bar'

[1, 2, 3].forEach(function(num) {
  console.log(num)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is valid in both this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/kawatevovabu/1/edit

and in version v0.10.26 of node.js. Perhaps this is a platform issue?